# Oracle: Recover backup in other different than original server

Tags: oracle

I'm really newbie about Oracle backup operations. I'm really new in this world and I need to know how to backup a DB schema and restore it in another machine under another schema name.

I cannot afford any mistake since I'll be doing this in our customer site, an making a small mistake could be the last one

I don't want to sound offensive, but doing this in MySQL is really easy, like this:

in server one:

```
$mysqldump --user=user --password=password db_to_backup > bc_name.sql
```

-after transfering the sql script to another server

in server two:

```
mysql>create database db_to_restore;
$mysql --user=user --password=password db_to_restore < bc_name.sql
```

I need to do the same using Oracle, I read some documentation but I'm still unsure how to do it:

- First: What's the equivalent of MySQL database in Oracle? tablespace?
- Second: I think these are the steps to get a backup

  ```
  mkdir /opt/oracle/dumptmp/
  CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY dumptmp AS '/opt/oracle/dumptmp/';
  expdp user/pass@tablespace directory=dumptmp dumpfile=dumptmp:full.dmp logfile=dumptmp:full.log full=y
  ```
- Third: Then I move the file "full.dmp" to the other server, but I'm not sure how to restore my backup file full.dmp into a new tablespace with a different name to the one it the backup was gotten from:

  ```
  SQLPLUS>create tablespace ts_something;
  ```

then I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Please advice me how to do it using command line commands since my customer does not have GUI tools intalled.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're planning to do this for the first time in your production environment? Does the customer know that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure you test this procedure in test or development environments before proceeding to perform it on production. Disclaimer: I'm not responsible if you bust any of your databases by misusing the following advice. Note that I'm also ignoring how tablespace storage is set up for your schemas, which you should definitely hold in consideration when creating new schemas.

Here is the simplest possible method using command line. You will need to use `exp` and `imp` utilities which come with complete Oracle database distributions. Assuming that you have the path to Oracle executables set correctly in your environment path, you will need to do:

1. Export your source schema on the source database server:

   ```
   [oracle@src_server ~]$ exp source_schema_username@SRC_SID owner=source_schema_username file=source_schema.dmp
   ```
2. Import your source schema into destination schema on the destination database server (assuming you have already created the destination schema, if not, see [`CREATE USER`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8003.htm), also make sure that destination schema user has RESOURCE role):

   ```
   [oracle@dst_server ~]$ imp system@DST_SID fromuser=source_schema_username touser=destination_schema_username file=source_schema.dmp
   ```

Note that you must run imp as a user that has DBA role. I'm using system here because this user typically exists on all Oracle databases and has DBA role. You will of course need to know the password for system user. You may not need to specify SIDs if ORACLE_SID is already set in your environment on both servers (`echo $ORACLE_SID`), however I wanted to be explicit here to make sure that you do not import into the wrong database.

For more information on usage of export and import utilities run `exp help=y` and `imp help=y`.

---

To answer your questions about Oracle:

> First: What's the equivalent of MySQL database in Oracle? tablespace?

Oracle equivalent is database name (db_name parameter). It identifies a database on Oracle database server(s). On a single instance database, this is also typically [Oracle SID](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/identifiers.html). On Oracle RAC, a single database will have many SIDs.

> Third: Then I move the file "full.dmp" to the other server, but I'm not sure how to restore my backup file full.dmp into a new tablespace with a different name to the one it the backup was gotten from:

You want to create a new user, which is identical to a schema in Oracle. Tablespaces are abstracted collections of disk locations where Oracle stores tables and indicies. For example, when you create a table, it has to be assigned to some tablespace.

Answer (score 1):

What you're explaining is not really a backup, more like schema export & import.

> but doing this in MySQL is really easy.

So is doing the same in Oracle.

`exp user/password@hoststring file=bc_name.dmp log=bc_name.log full=y statistics=none`

& to import it,

`imp new_user/new_password@hoststring file=bc_name.dmp log=bc_name.log full=y`

If `new_user` doesn't exist then create the users
`create user new_user identified by new_password`

and grant the rights
`grant create session,connect,imp_full_database to new_user`

Comment: While I realize exp & imp have been more or less depreciated, using exp & imp is perhaps slightly easier for a new user.

Comment: I would go for expdp and impdp rather than exp / imp for two reasons. First, exp / imp is rather depricated. Second, Oracle Datapump operations are a lot faster and you can better manage the export and import operations using set_parallel() function and better logging and other metatdata control features